Resolving path to file in public folder with Astro
I have an astro project that has a folder structure like this:
/
  src/
    index.astro
  public/
    data.json

I can import the data.json file when running locally (via npm run dev) using the relative path src="../public/data.json". However when I build the site (npm run build), the path to the JSON file breaks.
How should I set up my project so that I can successfully reference the data.json file while running locally, and also after building the site?

What do you want to do with the json file? link to it? see https://docs.astro.build/en/basics/project-structure/#public

@mb21 I need to pass the path to the file to Lottie (it's the animation data). The Lottie component I'm using manages the loading.

If you have it in public/data.json, then /data.json should work.

That works! A little un-intuitive for me since loading it from public/data.json works, but glad that I can at least make it consistent across local development and build/deploy. Thanks @mb21

See the astro docs.
If you have a file in public/data.json, then its path is /data.json.
To remember this, I always think of /favicon.ico.
